# Possible reasons that Windows XP dies on install?

Tags: windows-xp, installation, reboot

I'm trying to install Windows XP on an older computer. (note, it meets the system requirements) My problem is that it keeps rebooting during the "Registering Components" stage. What can cause this? What are some good things to look at to figure out whats happening?

Also, by Older Computer I mean it was made in probably 2003 or 2004. It has SATA ports on the mobo if that gives a hint as to the age.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible hardware issue.  Do you have a diagnostic tool you can run on the hardware either from the BIOS/Diagnostic partition or from a bootable device?

Comment: What kind of diagnostic tool? I've done memtest86+

Comment: I'm just assuming that the mobo is bad...

Answer (score 1):

Well that was weird.. I kept the default "WORKGROUP" and didn't set an "Organization" and this time it didn't die.. really weird.. may be a hardware problem still though

Comment: Well, actually then it died later when trying to setup network stuff... disabled the onboard network card, going to see how this will work

Comment: I don't know.. windows is installed but won't boot now.. Assuming it's a bad mobo...